# Python: logger duplicates messages on screen when logging to stdout and two files

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-multiprocessing

I have a logger with three handlers: common logfile for all processes, console and additional logfile for each process. Propagate is set to false, but the messages printed inside processes are doubled both on screen and general logfile.

Here is the code for main module:

```
import multiprocessing
import global_vars

import logging

logPath = 'logs'
fileName = "stdout.log"


def init_logger(secondary_logfile=None):
    logFormatter = logging.Formatter("%(asctime)s [%(processName)-12.12s] [%(threadName)-12.12s] [%(levelname)-5.5s] [%(filename)s:%(lineno)d] %(message)s")
    rootLogger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

    # first handler is general log
    fileHandler = logging.FileHandler("{0}/{1}".format(logPath, fileName))
    fileHandler.setFormatter(logFormatter)
    rootLogger.addHandler(fileHandler)
    # second handler is logging to console
    consoleHandler = logging.StreamHandler()
    consoleHandler.setFormatter(logFormatter)
    rootLogger.addHandler(consoleHandler) 

    # third handler is process-specific log
    if secondary_logfile:
        fileHandler1 = logging.FileHandler("{0}/{1}".format(logPath, secondary_logfile))
        fileHandler1.setFormatter(logFormatter)
        rootLogger.addHandler(fileHandler1)

    rootLogger.setLevel("DEBUG") # log everything

    rootLogger.propagate = False
    return rootLogger

rootLogger = init_logger()
logger = rootLogger.getChild(__name__)

# this class contains process-specific globals, shared among all functions
# of the specific process
class Shared():
    def __init__(self, shared_var, logger):
        self.shared_var = shared_var
        self.logger = logger
    def get(self):
        return self.shared_var

def make_global(process_id, logger):

    g = Shared(process_id, logger)
    global_vars.multiprocess_globals["g"] = g


def process_func(process_id):

    g = global_vars.multiprocess_globals["g"] # take g from process global scope
    # use g
    g.logger.debug('Message from specific logger {}, mirrored into main log: {}'.format(process_id, g.get()))


def run(process_id):

    # init secondary logger which will mirror into common log
    secondary_logger = init_logger(process_id)

    # create variable in process global scope
    make_global(process_id, secondary_logger)

    # run function which will use it
    process_func(process_id)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    logger.debug('This is log message in the main program')
    # init processes
    processes = []
    for i in range(1,4):
        p = multiprocessing.Process(target=run, args=(i,))
        p.daemon = True # for tensorflow https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/5448
        processes.append(p)

    # Run processes:

    for p in processes:
        p.start()

    for p in processes:
        p.join()

    logger.debug("This is again log message in main program")
```

Global_vars module contents is just:

```
multiprocess_globals = {}
```

Screen and main log (`logs/stdout.log`) output is:

```
$ python3 multiprocess_globals.py
2018-08-31 18:33:41,754 [MainProcess ] [MainThread  ] [DEBUG] [multiprocess_globals.py:75] This is log message in the main program
2018-08-31 18:33:41,756 [Process-1   ] [MainThread  ] [DEBUG] [multiprocess_globals.py:58] Message from specific logger 1, mirrored into main log: 1
2018-08-31 18:33:41,756 [Process-1   ] [MainThread  ] [DEBUG] [multiprocess_globals.py:58] Message from specific logger 1, mirrored into main log: 1
2018-08-31 18:33:41,757 [Process-2   ] [MainThread  ] [DEBUG] [multiprocess_globals.py:58] Message from specific logger 2, mirrored into main log: 2
2018-08-31 18:33:41,757 [Process-2   ] [MainThread  ] [DEBUG] [multiprocess_globals.py:58] Message from specific logger 2, mirrored into main log: 2
2018-08-31 18:33:41,757 [Process-3   ] [MainThread  ] [DEBUG] [multiprocess_globals.py:58] Message from specific logger 3, mirrored into main log: 3
2018-08-31 18:33:41,757 [Process-3   ] [MainThread  ] [DEBUG] [multiprocess_globals.py:58] Message from specific logger 3, mirrored into main log: 3
2018-08-31 18:33:41,758 [MainProcess ] [MainThread  ] [DEBUG] [multiprocess_globals.py:91] This is again log message in main program
```

How can I remove duplicating messages? Single process logfiles (1,2,3 etc) are fine.

PS Is it actually safe to intialize new loggers, which point to the same logfile? I just don't know, how to create setup like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved the problem by initializing rootLogger externally and then appending new handler inside the process:

```
import multiprocessing
import global_vars

import logging

logPath = 'logs'
fileName = "stdout.log"


#def init_logger(secondary_logfile=None):
logFormatter = logging.Formatter("%(asctime)s [%(processName)-12.12s] [%(threadName)-12.12s] [%(levelname)-5.5s] [%(filename)s:%(lineno)d] %(message)s")
rootLogger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

# first handler is general log
fileHandler = logging.FileHandler("{0}/{1}".format(logPath, fileName))
fileHandler.setFormatter(logFormatter)
rootLogger.addHandler(fileHandler)
# second handler is logging to console
consoleHandler = logging.StreamHandler()
consoleHandler.setFormatter(logFormatter)
rootLogger.addHandler(consoleHandler) 
rootLogger.setLevel("DEBUG") # log everything
rootLogger.propagate = False


# third handler is process-specific log
def init_logger2(secondary_logfile, rootLogger):
    fileHandler1 = logging.FileHandler("{0}/{1}".format(logPath, secondary_logfile))
    fileHandler1.setFormatter(logFormatter)
    rootLogger.addHandler(fileHandler1)

    return rootLogger

#rootLogger = init_logger()
logger = rootLogger.getChild(__name__)

# this class contains process-specific globals, shared among all functions
# of the specific process
class Shared():
    def __init__(self, shared_var, logger):
        self.shared_var = shared_var
        self.logger = logger
    def get(self):
        return self.shared_var

def make_global(process_id, logger):

    g = Shared(process_id, logger)
    global_vars.multiprocess_globals["g"] = g


def process_func(process_id):

    g = global_vars.multiprocess_globals["g"] # take g from process global scope
    # use g
    g.logger.debug('Message from specific logger {}, mirrored into main log: {}'.format(process_id, g.get()))


def run(process_id):

    # init secondary logger which will mirror into common log
    secondary_logger = init_logger2(process_id, rootLogger)

    # create variable in process global scope
    make_global(process_id, secondary_logger)

    # run function which will use it
    process_func(process_id)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    logger.debug('This is log message in the main program')
    # init processes
    processes = []
    for i in range(1,4):
        p = multiprocessing.Process(target=run, args=(i,))
        p.daemon = True # for tensorflow https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/5448
        processes.append(p)

    # Run processes:

    for p in processes:
        p.start()

    for p in processes:
        p.join()

    logger.debug("This is again log message in main program")
```